# Ubuntu - /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2: No such file or directory error

Tags: linux, ubuntu, raspberry-pi

I'm using ubuntu 20.04 on Raspberry Pi 4.
I try to run executable file (Hello world) made on my pc in Virtual box with same ubuntu 20.04 by Qt Creator and clang.

Error: x86_64-binfmt-P: Could not open '/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2': No such file or directory

I can't find ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 in the system at all, despite of newel version of libc6 setted in the system.

As I understand, I need to set up correct library path, but I don't understand how can I find library because of request 'find / -name "ld-linux-x86-64.so.2"' didn't help.

Please, help, I' m new with Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you are using `linux/x86_64 | emulated x86` and not ARM image in your virtual box.

Comment: there is amd64 in virtual box and arm64 in raspberry pi

Comment: @BilboBaggins Thanks for up vote and accepting the answer!